# django i18n msgstr quote is escaped twice

Tags: python, django, escaping

Some of my texts are escaped twice after upgrading from django 1.4 to `django 1.5`
For instance one label in my template "{{ field.label_tag }}" is displayed as "Email ou nom d&#39;utilisateur".
Is there something to change in the settings to avoid the double escaping?

The text "Email ou nom d'utilisateur" comes file django.po

This {{ field.label_tag }} come from the file signin_form.html of `userena package Vers 1.2.1`
"Email ou nom d'utilisateur" it is the traduction of "Email or username" in french, this come from the traduction in django.po
_(u"Email or username"), come from the file form.py line 147 of package userena

Comment: Are you sure it is due to the upgrade? Try `{{ field.label_tag|safe }}`

Comment: It works fine if I revert back to django 1.4. I tried the safe filter before but it doesn't work.

Comment: a no good solution maybe: `{% autoescape off %}"{{ field.label_tag }}"{% endautoescape%}`

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't work. Even with {% autoescape off %} the quote is escaped twice. Probably the bug come before the templating.

Comment: The text "Email ou nom d'utilisateur" comes file django.po

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved with django 1.6
You can update with :
`sudo pip install -U django`